# JSON String appears to be blank in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create web services using node js,express and mongoose.

this is my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

GetData = require('./models/women');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/shopping');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/api/getCategories',function(req,res){
  GetData.getCategory(function(err,getCategory){
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    res.json(getCategory);
  });
});

app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.send('Hi i am Madhura. Nice to Meet u. lets start creating web services');
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log('connected to Port 3000');
```

this is my women.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

var Category = module.exports = mongoose.model('',categorySchema);

module.exports.getCategory = function(callback,limit){
  Category.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

I am unable to understand this line

```
var Category = module.exports = mongoose.model('',categorySchema);
```

I have left this ' ' blank because I wanted to know what parameter is passed here

I watched a video about this, and could not find a conclusion. however, I simply followed the video and run the code. but my output is coming to be a null JSONArray "[]". Please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Problem solved? If not then your collection have not any records.

Comment: I think ```woman.js``` should have ```new mongoose.Schema``` instead of ```mongoose.Schema```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

var Category = mongoose.model('Category',categorySchema);

module.exports.getCategory = function(callback,limit){
  Category.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

The part you have made `''` contains the mongoose model name that you can use to refer the respective MongoDB collection. you can imagine a model name as replacement of `db.collectionname` for MongoDB. I have updated the codebase